# Is Einstein's riddle an example of a combinatorial design?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-designs

I have just learned a bit about combinatorial designs (BIBDs, constructing a ($b,v,r,k, \lambda$)-design, necessary conditions for a design, cyclic designs) and it reminded me a lot of Einstein's riddle (aka: [Zebra Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle))

Is Einstein's riddle an example of a combinatorial design?

If not, can it be made into a design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase "combinatorial design" can mean many things, but most commonly it refers to [block designs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design).

More broadly it might be interpreted in the context of [incidence structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_structure).  The Einstein riddle could be viewed as involving a [multipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph) which frames the connections between:

- five houses "in a row"
- five nationalities
- five kinds of pets
- five beverages drunk
- five colors for houses
- five brands of cigarettes

Thus one might relate the potential solution space to a complete multipartite graph $K_{5,5,5,5,5,5}$ with six parts, each of size five.  The *solution* amounts to a matching from one part (say, the houses) to each of the other parts, consistent with various "facts" espoused or implied by the puzzle.